# keeping track of completion of many tasks

Tags: wpf, task-parallel-library

I have a WPF application in which lots of event initiate tasks. Here's how I am doing it. But I am not happy about how it looks now

```
 var task = UpdatePersonModelAsync();
 taskCollection.Add(task);
 RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsUpdateInProgress));
 await task;
 taskCollection.Remove(task);
 RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsUpdateInProgress));
```

The property which shows/hides spinner

```
public bool IsUpdateInProgress => taskCollection.Count > 0;
```

I was going through the `Progress<T>` it seems like a call back.
When all the incoming tasks are completed a small spinner will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use `await Task.WhenAll(taskCollection.ToArray());` for waiting all the tasks you need to wait. After that, put the code for hiding the spinner below the `await` statement.

Comment: new tasks are incoming from different paths of code. Is there a way to run/group all the tasks in a logical place .. maybe TaskScheduler?

Comment: You can use a `BlockingCollection` for storing the tasks, and get a bunch of them by timer, if you need more control over them.

Comment: Thanks VMAtm. Please find the latest changes

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Your `Execute` is being called once, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a CustomTaskScheduler. I got it from https://www.infoworld.com/article/3063560/application-development/building-your-own-task-scheduler-in-c.html

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c18931/Understanding-the-NET-Task-Parallel-Library-TaskScheduler.htm

As tasks are created from various calls, I use the CustomTaskScheduler in Task.Factory.StartNew.

On debugging, I can get hits on QueueTask but Execute isn't getting called. What am I missing?

```
public sealed class CustomTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler, IDisposable
{
    public delegate void TaskStartedHandler(Task sender);
    public delegate void AllTasksCompletedHandler(IEnumerable<Task> sender);

    public event TaskStartedHandler TaskStarted;
    public event AllTasksCompletedHandler AllTasksCompleted;

    private BlockingCollection<Task> tasksCollection = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
    private readonly Thread mainThread = null;

    public CustomTaskScheduler()
    {
        mainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Execute));
        if (!mainThread.IsAlive)

        {
            mainThread.Start();
        }

    }

    private void Execute()
    {
        foreach (var task in tasksCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {

            var isStarted = TryExecuteTask(task);
            if (isStarted && TaskStarted != null)
            {
                TaskStarted(task);
            }
        }

        if(tasksCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable().All(m => m.IsCompleted))
        {
            AllTasksCompleted?.Invoke(tasksCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable());
        }
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        return tasksCollection.ToArray();
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        if (task != null)
        {
            tasksCollection.Add(task);
        }
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return false;
    }
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposing)
        {
            return;
        }

        tasksCollection.CompleteAdding();
        tasksCollection.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

The code is not yet complete. It would be great if someone can point to right direction

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new version

```
public class TaskTracker
    {
        public delegate void AllTasksCompletedHandler(object sender);
        public delegate void TaskStartedHandler();
        public event AllTasksCompletedHandler AllTasksCompleted;
        public event TaskStartedHandler TaskStarted;

        private object syncLock = new object();
        private SynchronizedCollection<Task> tasksCollection;
        private bool isTaskStartedNotified;
        private readonly uint delay;

        public TaskTracker(uint delayBeforeRemovingTasks)
        {
            tasksCollection = new SynchronizedCollection<Task>();
            delay = delayBeforeRemovingTasks;
        }

        public void Add(Task task)
        {

            if (!isTaskStartedNotified)
            {
                isTaskStartedNotified = true;
                TaskStarted?.Invoke();
            }

            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                RemoveTask(t);
            });

            tasksCollection.Add(task);
        }


        private async void RemoveTask(Task task)
        {
            await Task.Delay(300);
            await Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 tasksCollection.Remove(task);

                 if (tasksCollection.Count == 0)
                 {
                     isTaskStartedNotified = false;
                     AllTasksCompleted?.Invoke(tasksCollection);
                 }
             });
        }
    }
```